# Shortened convert_to_str function for big list/set/dict?

Tags: python, tostring

This is my `to_str()` for simplified list/set/dict display. Is there any built-in function already? Or any suggestion for simpler/better implementation?

```
def to_str(a):
    if type(a) == list:
        if len(a) > 5:
            return '[' + ','.join(map(to_str, a[:5])) + ',...]'
        return  '[' + ','.join(map(to_str, a)) + ',...]'
    elif type(a) == set:
        if len(a) > 5:
            return '{' + ','.join(map(to_str, list(a)[:5])) + ',...}'
        return '{' + ','.join(map(to_str, list(a))) + ',...}'
    elif type(a) == dict:
        if len(a) > 5:
            return '{' + ','.join(map(lambda x: '%s:%s'%(x[0], to_str(x[1])), [ (k, a[k]) for k in list(a)[:5]])) + ',...}'
        return '{' + ','.join(map(lambda x: '%s:%s'%(x[0], to_str(x[1])), [(k, a[k]) for k in list(a)])) + ',...}'
    return str(a)
```

Comment: I want the stringfied result not too long.

Comment: try pprint module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html

Comment: FYI: `type(a) == list` is better written as `isinstance(a, list)`

Comment: Cute. But why hard-code the 5 all over the place? Instead, make the number of displayed items a function arg, and give it a default value of 5. Also, it'd be better if you could reduce some of that repetition. I just noticed that you're outputting the `...` stuff even when `len(a)<5`. You probably _don't_ want that.

Comment: `itertools.islice(a, None, 5)` is likely to be more efficient than `list(a)[:5]` for "large" objects.